A good variable to make a regression model for gas usage over the years for a city
so I'm new to statistics, I'm trying to make a regression model in Excel, explaining why, or due to what variable, does the gas usage change over the years. I tried using a basic Y variable - Time - but that explains the issue in only 23%.
Do you have any ideas on what variable to use, when I'm trying to predict what amount of gas will be used up until the year 2037? It would need to be a variable that is either predicted or easy to predict. I've ran out of ideas.
Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Welcome to CV.  First, I wouldn't do statistics in Excel. It is POSSIBLE to do good analysis in Excel, but it's not easy. Excel is not designed for this. Second, what data have you got?  Third, for something like this, time series might be much better than regression.

Oh, and finally, requests for "a good variable" to do something are not really on topic here. This is a site about statistics. You might be better off asking experts in energy use.

@PeterFlom I know, but I need to use Excel for this project. It's for uni. I only really need to make a regression model and then calculate the prediction based on variables calculated in the regression "model". It allows me to see the "R square" that explains in what % a Y variable explains the phenomenon. If the P-value is lower than 0.05 I can use the "Intercept" and "X variable 1" to predict the usage of gas in the future. Sorry if I explained it a bit wierd. Also sorry for putting this topic out here, I just thought this counts as a statistic related topic.

It would be better if you came up with possible variables. What aspects of the city or the nation might impact on the city's gas usage?
